# How can I stop access of unregistered user in wp-content/uploads directory without using .htaccess file?

Tags: customization, directory, user-access

I want to give permission to only registered users into my `wp-content/uploads` directory and stop access for those users which are not members on my site.

Comment: What have you tried?  What *specific* problem are you running in to?  Why is `.htaccess` not a viable alternative?

Comment: because i want to redirect users to login page by programming in uploads folder/index.php  which is used in wp-content/uploads directory in url.and how can i code in index file to redirection of visitors to login page.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is engineered not to interfere with existing files, including `.htaccess` rules it generates to enable use of pretty permalinks.

Simply put you *cannot* make WP process or protect media files without *some* form of `.htaccess` or other web server configuration, because typically it handles them completely separately and WP doesn't interfere with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't give permission to the uploads directory to one user and blocking another. OK you can but you will have to configure Apache and the .htaccess file in the uploads directory with the user names and password,something that is not trivial to do from wordpress and result in a strange UI (one login for your site, and then login again to download files).

The way to make something like that work is to disable all access to the uploads directory and write code as part of wordpress to read the file and make it available to download on demand.

There are several plugins that do something similar, basically all the shopping ones that enable selling digital media, but not only them.

Comment: but i give permission to members only to access  contents into the media directory and not for visitors.

Comment: I don't understand this comment